# How to make an MDB to listen programmatically created queue

Tags: queue, jms, message-driven-bean, hornetq

Is the any option in hornetq to make an MDB to listen multiple queue. If so kindly provide a sample .

Answer (score 3):

No.  MDBs are deployment time objects that are wired via annotations or XML documents.  If you want, you can reuse the same class to listen to multiple destinations by setting up multiple MDBs in your ejb-jar.xml, all referring to the same class.  No, you cannot listen to programmatically created destinations because they must exist at deployment time.